# Switching on the power, system shows "Starting Windows" screen, then restarts always, then boots up second time properly

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have windows 7 ultimate on my system. Whenever I switch on the power button, I get "Starting Windows" screen which stays there for 2-3 minutes, then the LED lights of the CPU goes off for 3-4 seconds and it starts again automatically without me doing anything. This second time, it shows me a screen which reads the following:

> Start Windows Repair
>   Launch Windows Normally

I click on "Lanuch Windows Normally" and it boots successfully this time. Some of the times I have tried restoring it using Windows System Restore, also tried the second option - "Start Windows Repair".

But still, every time I switch on my PC, I see this sequence of events happening and it never starts the first time.

> Some test results:
>   When I restart, it works.
>   When I shut down and immediately turn on, it works.
>    When I shut down and turn on after 5-6 minutes, it works.
>    When I shut down and turn on after 14-15 minutes, this sequence of events happen again.

Please help me diagnose, what's the problem?

Comment: Check disk for errors with error correction enabled. It may help.

Comment: Does this only happen when the PC has been off for a while. What happens if the PC is shut down then immediately turned on? What happens if you select "Restart"?

Comment: Is it possible in the past you installed a second Windows 8/7/Vista (dual-boot) and then you unistalled it ?

Comment: When I restart, it works. When I shut down and immediately turn on, it works. When I shut down and turn on after 5-6 minutes, it works. When I shut down and turn on after 14-15 minutes, this sequence of events happen again.

Comment: I have never installed another operating system on top of first.

Answer (score 1):

You can try "StartUp Repair" from installation/recovery media (USB/DVD).

Run up to 3 times with rebooting after each run.

If problem persists you can try "inplace" reinstallation - you start **setup.exe** on installation media when booted to Windows 7. All your user files and settings will be preseved (some system settings will be reset to default). You have to reinstall some updates after that.

Comment: Even after formatting my system and re-installing the operating system, I am still having this problem. Now, can the problem be with insufficient power supply to hard disk? Because the system boots up eventually after it goes ON/OFF for random number of times.